# How to display data stored in node persist storage on the frontend while fetching the api?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

i am using node persist storage to store and retrieve data. i am able to sore data on API but dont know to retrieve and display on screen. Please help

Server Class. I have used node js to write code. The Api will store data in an array type as only 1 key is used. By this we display all data by calling only 1 key

```
var cors = require('cors') 
var express  = require('express');
var app = express();
const storage = require('node-persist');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(cors())

/* Initializing storage */
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
storage.init()

/* Get request for all tasks  */
app.get("/allTasks" , async(req,res) =>{
    const data = await storage.keys()
    console.log(data.toString)
    res.send(String(data))
})

/* Post request for tasks*/
app.post("/task" , jsonParser ,async(req,res) =>{

    try{
        let tasks =[];
        if((await storage.getItem("task")) !== undefined) {
            tasks = await storage.getItem("task");
        }
        const {task} = req.body;
        tasks.push(task);
        const resp = await storage.setItem('task' , tasks);
        res.status(201).send(resp);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
    });
   /* console.log("add called " , req.body) 
    const {task} = req.body;
    console.log(task);
    await storage.setItem(task);
    res.send('Task Added')
    
}) */

/* To listen the port */
app.listen(5000 , ()=> {
    console.log("Server has started")
});
```

This is the Tasks file. It has the UI text input and button. You enter the data and click enter button and data is stored in persist storage

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { ShowTasks } from "./Showtasks.js";

const Tasks = () => {
    const [task , setTask]  = useState("");
    

   const onSubmit = async e =>{
            e.preventDefault();
            try{
                    
                    const body = {task};
                    await fetch("http://localhost:5000/task" , {
                        method:"POST",
                        headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"},
                        body:JSON.stringify(body)
                    });
                    window.location = "/";
            } catch(err){
                console.error(err.message);
            }
                alert(task)
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">Enter The Task:</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" onChange={e=> setTask(e.target.value) }></input>
  <div class="input-group-append">
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onClick={onSubmit}>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>

<ShowTasks/>
        </Fragment>
    )
}


export default Tasks;
```

This is the Showtasks file. i am fetching data from API and storing in an array. Then using map function to display contents of array in table form. But it is not working. What to do ?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

export function ShowTasks(){

    const [tasks , setTasks] = useState([]) ;

    const getAllTasks = async () => {
        try {
            const resp =await fetch("http://localhost:5000/allTasks");
            console.log(resp.body)
          //  const data = await resp.json();
          //      console.log(data)
            if(resp.status == 200) {
                setTasks(resp.body)
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        getAllTasks();
    }, [])

    return( <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Tasks</th>
            </tr>
            {
                tasks.map((item,index)=>{
                    return(<tr key={index}>
                        <td>{item}</td>
                        console.log(resp)
                    </tr>)
                })
            }
        </table>
    </div>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `const data = await storage.keys()` will give you an array of strings
2. `console.log(data.toString)` will log the string `ƒ toString() { [native code] }` to the console
3. `res.send(String(data))` will send the string `key1,key2,.....` as a result to the browser client

Now you are expecting this to be an array on the client side, which it isn't. It's just a plain string

Does that help you?

Comment: This is the response i get after sending 3 data   {"key":"task","value":["Wake up","Brush Teeth","Take Bath"]}     Now i want to print this on browser screen

Comment: Store this info in react state and then `.map` over the value property in JSX

Comment: I Did that and it is not working

Comment: Can you please update your question with the latest code changes? So that we have a code base to work on